# CiviDiscount based on group membership

Tags: civievent, civimember, api, cividiscount

CiviDiscount gives an easy way to say, "Members get a lower price on a certain event", but I have the opposite situation - "attendees of a certain event get a discount on a membership".  Can anyone tell me how to do this?

It seems like I should be able to use the "advanced API filter" to find event attendees - but I can't find any examples of how to use that option.

Comment: hey jon - just skimming around topics related to CiviDiscount - any outcome on this?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion I believe I got it working using an API call like Lesley and Eileen suggested - but I don't work there anymore and don't have access to the db, so can't say for sure!

Answer (score 2):

Would using the [Group Based Pricing](https://civicrm.org/extensions/group-based-pricing) extension be an option? You could then in theory create a smart group for those contacts that have attended the event and use that group in the price configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I think the advanced api just allows you to add fields that would apply to contact.get api - e.g we use it like {"custom_67" : "Retiree"}

Answer (score 0):

Would this "Event Additional Signup" extension do the job: https://civicrm.org/extensions/event-additional-signup ?

Answer (score 0):

If 'Participant' is allowed as an 'entity' in the entity box, {"event_id": "nn"} where nn = event_id of the event whose participants should get a discount seems like it should work w/out your having to put attendees into a group