# Automatic discount if participant on other event

Tags: civievent, cividiscount

I want to give automatic discounts to participants if they already are participating in another event.

I have explored the API and have some clues on how to look up participants on "the other event". But I don't understand

- How can I check if the current registering contact is in that list
- How do I turn this into something that can be applied during/after the registration process
- Where do I put that code, or whatever the "something" is

I could not find any documentation for the "automatic discount" part of CiviDiscount. Hints on where to find that are also helpful.

Edit:

I found [CiviCRM Additional Events signup](https://github.com/aghstrategies/com.aghstrategies.eventmembershipsignup#civicrm-event-additional-signup) which sounded like a good fit but could not get that to work in a quick check, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

If CiviDiscount can be offered to those in a Smart Group, you could make a Smart Group of folk signed up to the first event.

Also read [CiviDiscount based on group membership](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/5215/cividiscount-based-on-group-membership) if you haven't already in case it gives other hints

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the best fit would be to use the advanced filter under automatic discounts. More information can be found here:

https://github.com/dlobo/org.civicrm.module.cividiscount/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Yes, that's kind of what I was asking, because the "example" does not explain enough, for me, how to create the "API string", what it should contain and how I make it contain the correct things so that it matches the current "registrant" to participant lists of some other event. Some I'd need some meat on that bone... Or where can I start reading up to understand "API string"?